# Fancybox issues with yii/ajax link

Tags: jquery, yii, fancybox

I have a rather large project that we're trying to migrate from jQuery UI dialogs to Fancybox.

In the past the logic was as such...

```
<a onclick="functionthatcreatesdialog()">Link</a>
...
function functionthatcreatesdialog() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({options}).dialog('open');
}
```

Fancybox works a bit different according to the API documentation, these are my attempts; I'm trying to pull an AJAX page:

```
<a id="startimport"
href="<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/index-dev.php/products/uploadCsvToServer">
Import from file</a>
```

And later on...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startimport').fancybox({someoptions});
    return false;
});
```

I *also* tried directly with `onclick=""`:

```
<a id="startimport"
href="<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/index-dev.php/products/uploadCsvToServer"
onclick="$('#startimport').fancybox();">
Import from file</a>
```

However, nothing works! I also tried some other combinations. Nothing.

Chrome's console didn't work as well, I thought the script might not be loading properly, but it was.

`$('#startimport').fancybox` returned:

```
function (options) {
        var index,
            that     = $(this),
            selector = this.selector || '',
            run      = function(e) {
                var what = $(this).blur(), idx = index, relType, relVal;

                if (!(e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.shiftKey || e.metaKey) && !what.is('.fancybox-wrap')) {
                    relType = options.groupAttr || 'data-fancybox-group';
                    relVal  = what.attr(relType);

                    if (!relVal) {
                        relType = 'rel';
                        relVal  = what.get(0)[ relType ];
                    }

                    if (relVal && relVal !== '' && relVal !== 'nofollow') {
                        what = selector.length ? $(selector) : that;
                        what = what.filter('[' + relType + '="' + relVal + '"]');
                        idx  = what.index(this);
                    }

                    options.index = idx;

                    // Stop an event from bubbling if everything is fine
                    if (F.open(what, options) !== false) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            };

        options = options || {};
        index   = options.index || 0;

        if (!selector || options.live === false) {
            that.unbind('click.fb-start').bind('click.fb-start', run);

        } else {
            D.undelegate(selector, 'click.fb-start').delegate(selector + ":not('.fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav')", 'click.fb-start', run);
        }

        this.filter('[data-fancybox-start=1]').trigger('click');

        return this;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried searching for solutions but nothing I tried helped.
I'm using the Yii framework btw.

Comment: Are you sure `fancybox` & `jQuery` are loaded ? Do you have any error in console when you click on the link ? Does your link works ?

Comment: My link works, both jQuery and Fancybox are definitely loaded (I'm using jQuery elsewhere in the page, and querying the .fancybox property for an element works), and yes, my link (otherwise) works and sends me to the AJAX page

Comment: Does fancybox appear with a blank popup or nothing happens ?

Comment: Just nothing. And no errors on the JS console.

Comment: Nice! Do you have a url I could look at ?

Comment: Could you check, if you're getting jQuery loaded a second time, when receiving your AJAX request. If so, try to disable it via CClientScript scriptMap.

Comment: unfortunately no, it's in a development repository
@schmunk Any way I could check? And could that potentially cause this? All other jQuery/UI functions work

Comment: Was just an idea, sometimes you initialize plugins, like fancybox, but if jQuery gets loaded a second time the initialization of the plugins are gone ... not sure with the other jQuery stuff ...

Comment: It's probably not related but i find it odd how you create URLs in Yii. You should better use `$this->createUrl('products/uploadToCsvServer')` (see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls)). Regarding your problem: Do you see a request to your target URL in the network tab in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you loaded both, fancybox js and css files (after jQuery).

Then, for this html link :

```
<a id="startimport" href="<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/index-dev.php/products/uploadCsvToServer">Import from file</a>
```

try :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startimport").fancybox({
        type: 'ajax'
    });
});
```

... (you don't need `return false;`).

If you have more than one link you want to open in fancybox, then you may need to switch to classes instead of IDs.

**Note** : ajax requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you are using fancybox v2.x keep in mind that if fancyBox cannot get the content `type`, it will try to guess it based on the `href` and it will silently fail if it does not succeed (this is different from previous versions where `ajax` was used as default `type` and an error message was displayed).